# Does this mean 'he was doomed'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Given the sentence:

> Now he'd done it. He hadn't even lasted two weeks. He'd be packing his bags in ten minutes. What would the Dursleys say when he turned up on the doorstep?

I guess that in this context *he’d done it* means “he’d been doomed.” Does ***do it*** has a meaning?

Comment: General reference: [That's done it](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/do?q=That%27s+done+it#do__98)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Now you've (gone and) [done it](http://www.metrolyrics.com/youve-really-gone-and-done-it-now-lyrics-duncan-sheik.html)" is a standard [idiom](http://www.fanfiction.net/s/1185834/1/Inuyasha-You-ve-Really-Done-It-This-Time) (it has [many](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d6CKhbXUk90) little [variations](http://www.sing365.com/music/lyric.nsf/Silly-Thing-lyrics-Sex-Pistols/3E44197C0577E25348256BDD000DC677)). It means **to make a serious mistake that has serious consequences that one cannot avoid being punished for**. So Harry's "doomed" to be punished for his mistake. He thinks he's going to be kicked out of Hogwarts.

Comment: Hard to find a definition on "now x've done it"

Comment: Yes, it is, but because of the contexts for the 4 examples I give, it's easy enough to create your own.

Comment: That is not what I meant. I wanted to flag this as a general reference, but it is not easy to find on the web although I know the idiom well

Comment: I see. You're right. I couldn't find one in the time I was willing to devote to searching for one.